# If a normalized sequence of finite measures converges weakly, does the same hold true for the nonnormalized one?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $E$ be a metric space, $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of finite nonnegative measures on $\mathcal B(E)$ and $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathcal B(E)$ s.t. $$\frac{\mu_n}{\mu_n(E)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mu\tag1$$ with respect to the to the topology of [weak convergence of measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures).

Assuming that $c:=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mu_n(E)<\infty$, are we able to deduce that the nonnormalized sequence $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent as well?

If not, does the other direction of this assertion hold, i.e. can we infer that the normalized sequence (i.e. the left-hand side of $(1)$) is convergent from knowing that the nonnormalized sequence is convergent? It's easy to see that $(\mu_n(E))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent in that case (since the function constantly equal to $1$ is bounded and continuous). So, this should be possible to obtain.

*Remark*: Without assuming $c<\infty$, the first implication is clearly wrong. We simply can consider any finite nonnegative measure $\nu$ on $\mathcal B(E)$ and set $\nu_n:=n\nu$ for $n\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $E = $ real line. Consider $\mu_{2n} = 2\delta_{ \{0 \} }$ and  $\mu_{2n-1} = \delta_{ \{0 \} }$, where $\delta_{ \{x \} }$  is a Dirac measure.

So the answer is negative.

The opposite is true if $lim_n \mu_n (E)$ (it exists, as you noticed) is not equal to $0$.

But if  $lim_n \mu_n (E) = 0$ we may have smth. like that: $\mu_{n} = \frac{(-1)^n + 1}{n}\delta_{ \{0 \} }$, that is counterexample, because normalized version of $\mu_{2n+1}$ doesn't exist.

**Addition.** Suppose that normalized sequence of measures converges to some measure $\nu$ and that $\mu_n(E) \to a \ne 0$, (hence $c < \infty$ and $a = \nu(E)$).
**Statement:** $\mu_n \to a \nu$ and $\nu$ is normalized (i.e. a probability measure).

Indeed, as $\lim_n \mu_n(E) \ne 0$ we have $\mu_n(E) \ne 0$ for all $n\ge n_0$. Thus $$\mu_n = \mu_n(E) \cdot \frac{\mu_n}{\mu_n(E)}.$$ Put $a_n =  \mu_n(E)$, $\nu_n = \frac{\mu_n}{\mu_n(E)}$. We want to show that $a_n \nu_n \to a \nu$. We know that  $\nu_n \to \nu$ and $a_n \to a \ne 0$.
By definition $\int f(x) d\nu_n \to \int f(x) d\nu$ for all bounded continuous $f$. Thus $$\int f(x) d(a_n \nu_n) = a_n \int f(x) d\nu_n \to a \int f(x) d\nu = \int f(x) d(a \nu)$$ and hence $a_n \nu_n \to a \nu$.

Further, $\nu(E) = \lim_n \nu_n(E) = 1$.

Moreover, under the condition $\lim_n \mu_n(E) \ne 0$ convergence of $\nu_n$ and convergence of $\mu_n$ are equivalent (because we may multiply and devide convergent sequence of measures by $ \mu_n(E)$).

Conclusion: if normalized measures converge then $\mu_n$ may not converge. If $\mu_n$ converges then in general case it doesn't mean that normalized measures converge (al least because normalized measures  may not exist). But  if $\mu_n$ converge and there is an additional condition $lim_n \mu_n(E) \ne 0$ then normalized measures converge.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate on why the opposite is true?

Comment: @0xbadf00d, I editet some typos and made and addition. Is there any questions?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I'm somehow confused by the way you've stated the result. My initial question was whether we can infer from $(1)$ that $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges. You've said "no" and provided a counterexample. Moreover, you said that the "opposite" would be true. The "opposite" would be the assertion that if $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges, then $(\mu_n/\mu_n(E))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges as well.

Comment: But now in your addendum, which I thought would provide a proof of this opposite assertion, it seems like you have shown that the answer to the initial question is suddenly positive; at least as long we assume that $\mu_n(E)$ converges to a positive value. Am I missing something?

Comment: @0xbadf00d, if normalized measures converge then $\mu_n$ may not converge: consider sequence $\delta_0, 2\delta_0,\delta_0, 2\delta_0, ...$. If $\mu_n$ converges then in general case it doesn't mean that normalized measures converge (al least because normalized measures  may not exist as in my example). But  if $\mu_n$ converge and there is an additional condition $lim_n \mu_n(E) \ne 0$ then normalized measures converge.

Comment: I guess we have a mismatch in terminology. What do you mean when you say "if normalized measures converge"? Do you mean that "$\mu_n/\mu_n(E)$ converges" or do you mean that "$\mu_n(E)=1$ and $\mu_n$ converges"? If I'm not completely mistaken what you wrote, you've shown that if $\mu_n/\mu_n(E)$ converges and $\mu_n(E)$ converges, then $\mu_n$ converges. Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: It seems to me that you're concluding exactly the opposite of what you've shown. Indeed, in your proof you literally write "we know that $\nu_n\to\nu$" and $\nu_n$ is precisely the sequence $\mu_n/\mu_n(E)$ of normalized measures. So, it seems like this is what you are assuming and from which you are showing that even the unnormalized sequence converges.

Comment: @0xbadf00d, you understood me right. By "normalized measures" I imply $\nu_n = \frac{\mu_n}{\mu_n(E)}$. And from convergence of $\nu_n$ (if we have additional assumption $\lim_n \mu_n(E) \ne 0$) it follows, that $\mu_n$ converges. Thus we got statement: "if normalized measures converges and there's additional condition then measures $\mu_n$ converge."

Comment: @0xbadf00d, "you're concluding exactly the opposite of what you've shown" Maybe I don't understand something, but I don't see it. Could you please indicate more specifically what the problem is?

Comment: (a) You wrote "if $\mu_n$ converge and there is an additional condition $lim_n \mu_n(E) \ne 0$ then normalized measures converge." But that is **not** what you've shown. You have shown that if the normalized sequence $\nu_n=\mu_n/\mu_n(E)$ converges and, additionally, $\mu_n(E)$ converges to a positive number, then $\mu_n$ converges as well. (b) I've accepted your answer since I'm sure we actually mean the same thing. I've provided a slightly more general result in a [separate answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3968321/47771). Please let me know whether you agree or not.

Comment: @0xbadf00d, now I noticed. Edited version of the statement: under the condition $\lim_n \mu_n(E) \ne 0$ convergence of $\nu_n$ and convergence of $\mu_n$ are equivalent (because we may multiply and divide  convergent sequence of measures by $ \mu_n(E)$).

Answer (score 1):

By the same argument as [presented by Botnakov N.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3964926/47771) we can even show more:

Let $\mathcal M(E)$ denote the space of finite signed measures on $\mathcal B(E)$ equipped with the total variation norm $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|$, $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}$ be a net in $\mathcal M(E)$ with $$c:=\lim_{t\in I}\left\|\mu_t\right\|\ne0\tag2$$ and $\mu\in\mathcal M(E)$ with $$\left(\frac{\mu_t}{\left\|\mu_t\right\|}\right)_{t\in I}\to\mu\tag3$$ with respect to the topology of [weak convergence of measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures). Then, $$\mu_tf=\left\|\mu_t\right\|\frac{\mu_t}{\left\|\mu_t\right\|}f\xrightarrow{t\in I}c\mu f\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in C_b(E)\tag4;$$ i.e. $$(\mu_t)_{t\in I}\to c\mu\tag5.$$

Comment: @BotnakovN. Thank you for the confirmation. Are you sure that we can make the latter conclusion? Note that we are dealing with signed measures now.  So, $\left\|\mu_t\right|=|\mu_t|(E)$. However, even when we are assuming that $\mu_t$ and $\mu$ are nonnegative, then $(2)$ and $(3)$ together only yield $c=\lim_{t\in I}\mu_t1=c\mu1=c\mu(E).$ This yields that $\mu$ must be a probability measure in the first place.

Comment: Indeed, didn't notice, that these are signed measures now. In case when they are nonnegative I used another notation with $\nu$ instead of $\mu$ in (3). In this notation in case $\lim \mu_n(E) \ne 0$ we have $\nu_n \to \nu$ iff $\mu_n     \to \mu$.