# If $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges in $L^p$, does the sequence of normalized functions converge as well?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a measure space and $p\ge1$. If $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq L^p(\mu)$ and $f\in L^p(\mu)$ with $$\left\|f_n-f\right\|_{L^p(\mu)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag1,$$ can we infer that $\left(\frac{f_n}{\left\|f_n\right\|_{L^p(\mu)}}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is $L^p(\mu)$-convergent as well?

Note that clearly $\left\|f_n\right\|_{L^p(\mu)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\left\|f\right\|_{L^p(\mu)}$. So, the answer should be positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the measure space is finite and $f_n$ is the constant function $(-1)^{n} /n$ then $f_n \to 0$ in any $L^{p}$ but $\frac {f_n} {\|f_n\|_p}$ does not converge.

The conlusion holds if $\|f\|_p \neq 0$ and this is general fact valid in any normed linear space:

Let $(x_n)$ be sequence in a normed linear space $X$ such that $\|x_n-x\| \to 0$. If $x \neq 0$ then $\frac {x_n} {\|x_n\|} \to \frac x {\|x\|}$

Proof: $|\|x_n\|-\|x\|| \leq \|x_n-x\| \to 0$ so $\|x_n\| \to \|x\|$. It is quite easy to see that $\|x_n-x\| \to 0$ together with $a_n \to a, (a_n,a \in [0,\infty)) $ implies $a_nx_n \to ax$. (Use triangle inequality). Now take $a_n=\frac 1 {\|f_n\|_p}, a=\frac 1 {\|f\|_p}$.

Comment: Your counterexample works in an arbitrary normed space as well if we take $x_n=\frac{(-1)^n}nx_0$ for an arbitrary $x_0\ne0$.

Comment: It's not a special case of this question, but can we obtain a similar result for a sequence $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of finite signed measures, i.e. if this sequence converges wrt the topology of weak convergence of measures, does the normalized sequence (divided by the total variation norm) converge as well? At least for nonnegative measures?

Comment: It seems like that the analogue result for the topology of weak convergence and sequences normalized by the total variation norm does not hold. However, the converse implication should hold: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3968321/47771. Do you agree?